# Valor de variables undefined

Tags: angular, ionic, geolocalización, ionic4, angular8

Tengo una aplicación en angular 8 y ionic 4 en la cual se requiere mostrar las coordenadas del dispositivo. Cuando quiero mostrar las coordenadas en la consola del navegados, estas son undefined pero cuando las pongo dentro de una suscripción estas si tienen valor ¿Qué puede estar pasando?.

Tengo el siguiente código

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

    lat:number;
    lon:number;

    constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {
        this.getCoordinates();
    }

    getCoordinates() {
        let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
        watch.subscribe((data) => {
            this.lat = data.coords.latitude;
            this.lon = data.coords.longitude;

            console.log(this.lat); //Ya tiene valores
            console.log(this.lon); //Ya tiene valores
        });
        console.log(this.lat); //undefined
        console.log(this.lon); //undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es porque la suscripción es asíncrona. Dentro de la suscripción debes colocar el código que deseas que se ejecute luego de obtener las coordenadas.

El orden de ejecución puedes verlo así:

1. Se ejecuta la instrucción `watch.subscribe(callbak);` En ese momento se inicia una espera en segundo plano hasta que `watch` emita un valor, no se sabe cuanto tiempo durará la espera.
2. Se ejecuta `console.log(this.lat);` Esta instrucción se ejecuta inmediatamente después de `watch.subscribe(callbak);`, antes de que `watch` haya emitido un valor por eso es `undefined`.
3. `watch` emite un valor, y ese se encuentra dentro del cuerpo del callback de la suscripción, en este momento `this.lat` ya tiene un valor. Por eso dentro de la suscripción se coloca el código a ejecutar.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, me ah explicado bien el proceso.